# calculating CDF of kth order statistic

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function, order-statistics

I have recently started probability and statistics on my own. Pls help in understanding below.

$x_{(k)}$ is kth smallest random variable from sample of n iids ($x_1 \to x_n$)

For calculating CDF of kth orderstatistic means $x_{(k)} \leq x , x_{(k+1)}>x, ....x_{(n)}>x$ $\\ = $$n \choose k$$ F(x)^{k}(1-F(x))^{n-k}$

But in below pic, why are they breaking in to some disjoing subevents? Above 1 is just enough right?

source page 1 of [http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/Lecture14.pdf](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7E2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/Lecture14.pdf)

[image]

Comment: The event$$x_{(k)} \leq x , x_{(k+1)}>x, ....x_{(n)}>x$$is not the event$$x_{(k)} \leq x$$associated with the cdf of $x_{(k)}$. The $k$-th order statistic being less than $x$ does not say anything about the higher-order order statistics.

Comment: yes sir. We need only x(k) right. We fixed it with respect to x. it ensures x(1) to x(k) less than x. Why should i care about others? yes i agree some of them may be less than x and some more than x.I am calculating cdf of F_x(k) only right

Comment: @Xi'an kindly elaborate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slides are about decomposing the event
$$\{X_{(k)}\le x\}$$
into manageable disjoint events. When $X_{(k)}\le x$ one and only one of the following events occurs

- all $X_i$'s are less than $x$, i.e., $X_{(n)}\le x$
- $X_{(n)}> x$ and all others are less than $x$, i.e., $X_{(n-1)}\le x$
- $\ldots$
- $X_{(k+1)}\le x$ and all others are more than $x$, i.e., $X_{(k+2)}> x$
- $X_{(k)}\le x$ and all others are more than $x$, i.e., $X_{(k+1)}> x$

Therefore the probability that $X_{(k)}\le x$ is the sum of the probabilities of these $n-k+1$ disjoint events. And
$$\mathbb P(X_{(i)}\le x < X_{(i+1)})=\underbrace{{n \choose i}}_{\text{pick $i$}\atop{\text{$X_t$'s}\atop\text{ among $n$}}}\times \underbrace{F(x)^i}_{\text{$i$ iid $X_t$'s}\atop\text{less than $x$}}\times\underbrace{(1-F(x))^{n-i}}_{\text{$n-i$ iid $X_t$'s}\atop\text{more than $x$}}$$

Comment: understood now sir. THank you